# Something strange in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

`a` is a numpy array and `a.T` is it's transpose. Once I add `a` and `a.T` as `a += a.T`, the answer isn't expected. Could any one tell me why? Thanks.

```
import numpy 

a = numpy.ones((100, 100))
a += a.T
a

array([[ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       ..., 
       [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `a.T` is only a view on `a`, which means they hold the same data. Now:

```
 a += a.T
```

Adds `a.T` in place to `a`, but while doing so, changes `a.T` (as `a.T` points at the same data). Since the order of accessing `a` is a bit more complex, this fails (and you should not trust the result to be reproducable, because it will change when you change `np.setbufsize`.

To avoid it both of these will work, though the first version seems cleaner to me.

```
a = a + a.T
a += a.T.copy()
```